# Unable to install ctcdecode using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I am trying to installing ctcdecode using

```
pip install ctcdecode
```

But it's giving me some error.
I also tried using

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode.git
cd ctcdecode && pip install wget && python setup.py install
```

and also using

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode.git
cd ctcdecode && pip install .
```

All 3 times I get the same error below:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kpg860t9\\ctcdecode_489ee2f1bf954a61b0e7fbb40457d793\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kpg860t9\\ctcdecode_489ee2f1bf954a61b0e7fbb40457d793\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8gh80i00\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\ctcdecode' Check the logs for full command output
```

Help, please.
Thanks.

Comment: The error says to check the logs. Could you edit your question and post the important part of the log?